# Showing error while using Blob

Tags: javascript, blob, web-worker

I have used Blob() in javascript to generate an url. This url is supposed to be used in the web worker i.e Worker().

I have written this code:

```
var workerJs = $('#worker').html()
var blob = new Blob([workerJs], {type: 'mimeString'})
var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
var worker = new Worker(blobURL)
```

But I am continuously getting this error:

The resource from this URL is not text: blob:30b85aca-40e3-465a-94b1-32947ac8f45

Answer (score 1):

The `type` option to the `Blob` constructor should be a mime type, not sure where you got the idea to use `mimeString` for that. It should work if you use `text/javascript`:

```
var blob = new Blob([workerJs], {type: 'text/javascript'})
```